# Parsing XML Using XPATH for Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am new to Python - a few days old - and I would appreciate some help.

I want write a python code to parse the below XML as below:-

**ServingCell----------NeighbourCell**
 L41_NBR3347_1----------L41_NBR3347_2
 L41_NBR3347_1----------L41_NBR3347_3
 L41_NBR3347_1----------L41_NBR3349_1
 L41_NBR3347_1----------L41_NBREA2242_1

```
<LteCell id="L41_NBR3347_1">
 <attributes>
  <absPatternInfoTdd><unset/></absPatternInfoTdd>
  <additionalSpectrumEmission>1</additionalSpectrumEmission>
  <additionalSpectrumEmissionList><unset/></additionalSpectrumEmissionList>
  <LteSpeedDependentConf id="0">                   
    <attributes>                                    
     <tReselectionEutraSfHigh>lDot0</tReselectionEut
     <tReselectionEutraSfMedium>lDot0</tReselectionE
    </attributes>                                   
   </LteSpeedDependentConf>                         
   <LteNeighboringCellRelation id="L41_NBR3347_2">  
    <attributes>                                    
     <absPatternInfo><unset/></absPatternInfo>      
   </LteNeighboringCellRelation>                    
   <LteNeighboringCellRelation id="L41_NBR3347_3">  
    <attributes>                                    
     <absPatternInfo><unset/></absPatternInfo>      
   </LteNeighboringCellRelation>                    
   <LteNeighboringCellRelation id="L41_NBR3349_1">  
    <attributes>                                    
     <absPatternInfo><unset/></absPatternInfo>                            
   </LteNeighboringCellRelation>                    
   <LteNeighboringCellRelation id="L41_NBREA2242_1">
    <attributes>                                    
     <absPatternInfo><unset/></absPatternInfo>      
     <absPatternInfoTdd><unset/></absPatternInfoTdd>
```

Comment: Look for bs4 or lxml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the xml path you produced is not correct: you need to close the tags your open.
For example **attributes** is opened and not closed.

```
   <LteNeighboringCellRelation id="L41_NBR3349_1">  
       <attributes>                                    
       <absPatternInfo>
          <unset/>
       </absPatternInfo>                            
   </LteNeighboringCellRelation>
```

I refactored (and simplified it a little bit) the xml to correct it.

```
<LteCell id="L41_NBR3347_1">   
   <attributes>                    
      <LteNeighboringCellRelation id="L41_NBR3347_2">                                          
      </LteNeighboringCellRelation>                    
      <LteNeighboringCellRelation id="L41_NBR3347_3">         
      </LteNeighboringCellRelation>                    
      <LteNeighboringCellRelation id="L41_NBR3349_1">                                                             
      </LteNeighboringCellRelation>                    
      <LteNeighboringCellRelation id="L41_NBREA2242_1">
      </LteNeighboringCellRelation>
   </attributes> 
</LteCell>
```

Here is the code to parse and display it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("XmlExample.xml")
result = ''
root = tree.getroot()

for e in tree.findall('./attributes/LteNeighboringCellRelation'):#attributes/LteNeighboringCellRelation
    print(root.attrib['id']+'----------'+e.attrib.get('id'))
```

Hope that helps,